# How to attach cable to a solder eyelet?

Tags: resistors, connector, soldering, wiring

I believe that's what such connector is called. I want to attach 18 awg wire to it. Is slide on terminal the best choice?

[image]

Comment: There's a reason it's called a *solder* lug.

Comment: You can solder or use a suitable sized quick connect terminal

Comment: Duplicate of [Why do the leads of some resistors have holes?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/616844/why-do-the-leads-of-some-resistors-have-holes) Also see [What is a good way to reinforce wire soldered to solder lugs?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/487647/what-is-a-good-way-to-reinforce-wire-soldered-to-solder-lugs)

Comment: > There's a reason it's called a solder lug. Except that it's called a solder eyelet. A solder lug is a flat, long terminal with two holes, one for a stud, one for a soldered wire.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I've seen these called solder lugs often enough that I don't think it's wrong to call it that. Language changes over time.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution is almost always to solder when you have the option. Stick the peeled wire through the lug, then bend it into a hook. Ensure that it won't move during soldering. Solder with a large, flat "screwdriver" kind of tip.

Comment: After soldering, add a short length of heat-shrink tube to the tag plus cable. If you don't mechanically reinforce the interface between the wire and the solder joint, then any movement of the wire puts considerable strain on its individual strands, which will break, gradually weakening the connection.

Comment: @jayben Shrink tube won't do much for mechanical stability. There are plastic clips with adhesive that you could mount on the surface, then have them hold down the cable. Or just route the cable to a nearby cable tray etc. It all depends on what the installation looks like.

Comment: @Lundin It provides stain relief. Otherwise exposed strands buckle outward, kink, and stay that way, and other strands follow into the newly opened space.

Comment: @Lundin well I think the wire I have is thicker than the hole. that's why I ask if there're alternatives

Comment: If the hole is too small, ignore it, and solder the wire parallel to the tag, or consider using smaller wire. I have seen various professional installations that use heat-shrink to protect against minor flexing of the connection (e.g. during assembly), so I'd strongly advocate its use. If there is major flexing, then you do need to anchor the cable elsewhere.